# Updating dimension tables using SQL Server (BIDs or Data Tools)

Tags: sql-server, etl, business-intelligence, bids, dimension

I'm quite confused as to how I'm supposed to be adding dimension members to my data warehouse. Let's say that TOWN_NAME is a dimension table that links town_Id to a town_name. So, now, I have 1000 customer names, and they are from 9 towns. Suddenly, in my next ETL process, a customer ends up being added whose town is not amongst that 9 towns i have in my dimension. So I need to add a member to my dimension table. Which step/process in BIDS or DATA TOOLS (BIDS 2012) would have I to use? How should this be one? I'm quite lost as to what could be done.

Comment: In general, my assumption would be that you're using an SSIS package to populate your data warehouse and reprocess your cube.  You should have a step within your SSIS package that also keeps your dimension tables up-to-date.

Comment: Yes I'm using an SSIS package. But which step would that be?!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your SSIS package looks like.  Suffice to say that there are probably tasks in it that read data from some source, tasks that process and manipulate some of that data, and tasks that load the data into your data warehouse. I expect that one of those tasks loads data into your dimension table.  That task needs to be aware of the new dimension member and get it into your dimension table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual pattern - regardless of what tools you're using to populate your data warehouse - is to populate your Dimension **before** you populate your Fact, precisely to avoid this problem.

The usual way to do things is to have a package which pulls out your Dimension data from your source system(s), and then load any new rows into your Dimension table. Then, when your Fact table load happens later in the process you look-up the ID column from the Dimension using the town name. Your Fact data should then be loaded into the Fact table with the ID for the relevant town as one of its column values.

Specifically, in SSIS, you can manage this by creating a package which does your Dimension table load, and another package in the same project which does your Fact table load. Then you can control the order these happen in a couple of different ways:

- You can create a third package which uses two Execute Package tasks to call the Dimension package first, and then the Fact package.
- You could create a SQL Server Agent Job which first calls the Dimension package, then calls the Fact package.

If you want to be able to run everything from within Visual Studio in order in one go, then go with the first option.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I was wondering that when you say "pop your dimension BEFORE facts", you mean to say that the package should handle dimension before facts, right? Because dimensions could keep growing and prior to the loading of facts, I cannot tell whether they would grow or not. So I should use the fact table data stream FIRST to populate/update my dimensions before proceeding to populate my fact tables. Am I correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: I usually write separate queries which load the Dimensions earlier in the process - so in your case, you could query your source to get a list of all of the towns in the source system, and insert any new ones into the Dimension. Then when the Fact load runs, any Dimensions it relies on are already populated. It's up to you exactly how you form those queries and you could just reuse the Fact queries, but you may find that performs more slowly than writing specific queries which only cover the necessary data items for each Dimension.

Comment: I answered a similar question here, in case it's of any further help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29433638/3964881

Comment: @LearnByReading - Just realised I forgot to tag you, just doing so to make sure you see these comments. I'll delete this comment once you've seen everything. Let me know if the above comments help - if so I'll edit the information from them into my answer. Thanks!